# why can't i use a tkinter window while using the python shell

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to print text in the shell and to use a tkinter window but they can't run at the same time, is there a way that I can use them at the same type

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


root = Tk()
class imgs:
    global img
    def __init__ (self , img ):
        self.img = img
        global img1
        img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("C:/Users/ASUS/pixel/"+img+".png"))
        l = Label(image = img1)
        l.pack()
```

I used this code to make the image appear on the code, I just type 
`imgs("myimg")`
and after the code ends the image appears, what can I do to use the two windows at the same time.

Comment: Please edit the code to be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What do you mean _"shell"_?  A _"Terminal"_? The _Python IDLE_?  And also what do you mean _"use the two windows at the same time"_?